# Sharing SQLRepository and connectionstrings between ConsoleApp and Website within same Solution

Tags: web, web-config, console-application, connection-string, app-config

I have a solution with a Console Application Project and a Website Project in it. Both projects connect to a database and have the same connection string setup. The connection string is actually defined twice: 1) once in the App.config of the Console Application Project and 2) another time in the Web.config file of the Website Project. Both project have a SQLRepository class used to query the database.

The question is:

> Is it better practice having the solution setup as I do, or is it
>   better (or even possible since one project is a console app and the
>   other is a website) to share the connection string and SQLRepository
>   class between the two projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went for keeping two connection strings in App.config and Web.config.
This setup is a bit more flexible in case you have to make changes to the website without affecting the console app